# VBA or to not VBA for compare and count cell data with unique ids

Tags: vba, count, compare

I have 2 columns in a spreadsheet with 50k+ rows. 
One is for a transaction ID, and one for a processor of said transaction.

A single transaction could have multiple processors, and I need to count how many unique ticketers there are for each transaction.

Example:

```
TDS13456        HP
TDS13456        DELL
TDS13456        COMPAQ
TDS13456        DELL
TDS13456        HP    
TDS13456        DELL
```

I need to somehow return the values 3, HP, DELL & COMPAQ for that transaction ID.

I also need to go through the entire sheet for this...

Please help!

Comment: You could create a pivot table in order to group the entries with the same values. You can read more about pivot tables at the [Microsoft Office page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx).

Comment: yup - that's what I went with! Was a lot easier than I thought it would be.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a Dictionary (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164502(v=office.10).aspx)

Using the transaction ID as the key value and link the transaction ID to an ArrayList of processors. Iterate through the first column of transaction IDs and check if the key exists already. If the key doesn't exist, add the key to the dictionary. Next check to see if the item in column 2 exists in that transaction ID's ArrayList of processors, if it doesnt then add it to the ArrayList. At the end you can print out the size of the ArrayList for each transaction ID as well as the items in the Arraylist

Comment: The pivot table worked well for me, thanks for taking the time to reply!